# Is it Possible with out using Iframes we can display HTML page inside an other Html Page?

Tags: html

I am new to HTML5,i need to display one HTML page Inside an other HTML page with out using frames&iframes.
 please help me.

Comment: Accepting an answer to your question on stackoverflow is greatly appreciated and will encourage other programmers to answer your questions!

Comment: Bear in mind most of the solutions below will require you calling your CSS/JS in the "master" page. Also, if you take the `AJAX` approach you will have to use `live` events so the javascript can recognize the elements that were inserted after the `DOM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably be hosting your HTML web pages in some kind of a server. So in an Apache server you can use [PHP include() function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).
Or in IIS you can use [ASP #include directive](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp)

Answer (score 1):

the other way is to 'scrape' other web pages via AJAX and insert contents into an element on your page.